# Python - how to make python package with argparse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse, packaging

I wrote my project in python and now I want to pack it into python package like here : [Python packaging tutorial](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html#picking-a-name). The thing is I don't know how to properly pack my main.py ( I named it __ init __.py same like in tutorial)  where the arg parse is being used. My file structure currently looks like this:

```
information_analyzer/
   information_analyzer/
   __init__.py
   ArticleFile.py
   ArticleInspector.py
   SearchEngine.py
setup.py
.gitignore
README.md
```

Here is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup
setup(name='information_analyzer',
      version='0.3',
      description='Phrase and article analyzer',
      url='https://github.com/my_repo_link',
      author='Name Surname',
      author_email='mail@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['information_analyzer'],
      include_package_data=True,
      zip_safe=False)
```

Here is my __ init __.py:

```
import argparse
import sys

from information_analyzer.information_analyzer.ResultsChecker import check_result
from information_analyzer.information_analyzer.SearchEngine import SearchEngine
from information_analyzer.information_analyzer.ArticleInspector import ArticleInspector


def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Information analyzer')
    parser.add_argument('--phrase', default=None, type=str, help='Phrase for verification')
    parser.add_argument('--articleURL', default=None, type=str, help='URL to article')

    args = parser.parse_args()
    articleURL=args.articleURL # for example http://fedsalert.com/donald-trump-dead-from-a-fatal-heart-attack/
    phrase=args.phrase

    if(phrase is None and articleURL is None):
        print("You must specify phrase or article URL to run the program.")
        sys.exit()

    if phrase is not None:
        search_engine = SearchEngine()
        check_result(phrase, search_engine)

    if articleURL is not None:
        article_inspector=ArticleInspector(articleURL)
        article_inspector.print_all_informations()
```

When I installed `pip install .` and tried to import it in python console I got that info:

```
>>> import information_analyzer
>>> information_analyzer.main()
```

> AttributeError: module 'information-analyzer' has no attribute 'main'

Comment: Where is your \_\_init\_\_.py? Is it in the top-level information_analyzer or in information_analyzer/information_analyzer? Your tree suggests the former while it must be the latter.

Comment: It is in information_analyzer/information_analyzer/

Comment: Why import `from information_analyzer.information_analyzer`? Shouldn't it be just `from information_analyzer…`? Seems you have an excessive 'information_analyzer' subdirectory, so you can try `from information_analyzer.information_analyzer import main`